# IPC with Ruby 1.8.5

Tags: ruby, ipc, sketchup

I need to do IPC with Ruby 1.8.5. The catch is that it's the Ruby that ships with Google SketchUp, and is only a subset of the full Ruby API. So for instance, there's no Socket class, and no DRb.

What are some other way's of doing IPC with Ruby? Anything that uses the File class, like memory mapped files, or something like that? I'm completely new to IPC, so I apologize if I missed something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of SketchUp ships with Ruby 1.8.6. You can download (if you haven't already) the core Ruby API, and just `require` whatever files you need, to implement your script.

Testing non-SketchUp Ruby code, is much easier outside of SketchUp, with the command line, or an editor like SciTE. Then you can add your SketchUp code for tests within the application.

[Ruby Download](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/)

[SciTE Download](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDownload.html)